# Quit gdb while the target keeps running on STM32H7

Tags: gdb, stm32

I am working on a device with two STM32H7 (for the moment two STM32H7 EVAL2 boards). I want to debug on one (with STMicro Cube IDE) and just be able to restart (reset and run) the second one. I am debugging remotely so I don't want to press the board reset button.

My idea is to use STLink gdbserver (that I already use for the remote debug of the first MCU) only to reset and run the second MCU.

I was able to reset and run the target only with the `continue` command but this command is blocking GDB.

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb -q -ex "set confirm off" -ex "target remote xxx" -ex "monitor halt reset", -ex "continue"
```

The command `run` is not supported.

Is it possible to reset and run a target then quit GDB while the target keeps running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After connecting to the target with `target remote ...` you should be able to use the `detach` command.  This will tell GDB to close the remote connection but leave the remote running.

Once detached you should be able to `quit` GDB without causing your remote target to be killed.

Comment: Thank you. It worked if I do: `target remote ...`  then `monitor reset halt` then `detach` then `quit`

Comment: But the problem is that the command `detach` seems to close the remote `gdbserver` so I can't run my script (to reset the target) several times

Comment: Does connecting with `target extended-remote` help at all?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Just took a read of https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2576-stm32cubeide-stlink-gdb-server-stmicroelectronics.pdf - is this the gdbserver you are using?  I suspect you need to start the server with the `-e` option to place it in persistent mode.  If this is correct I'll update the answer to include this information.

Comment: Yes it is. And I already launch the server with -e